# Check relation between expressions of variance and mean value.

Tags: probability

I try to check relations between following expressions (it means: $\ge$, or $\le$ or lack of relation.

**1.**
$E(XY)...E(X)E(Y)$
If $X=Y$ then $E(XY)\ge E(X)E(Y)$ because $Var X \ge 0$.
Now, lets consider: 
Choose random number (one number) from set $\{1,2,3\}$.
$X$ - number is even
$Y$ - number is divisible by $3$, $X,Y$ are Bernolli's variables.
$E(XY) = 1\cdot P(X=1\wedge Y = 1) = 0$
$E(X)E(Y)= 1 \cdot P(X=1) \cdot 1P(Y=1) = 1/3 \cdot 1/3 = 1/9 > 0$

**2.** $Var(X+Y) = VarX + Var Y$
$Var(X+Y)...VarX+VarY$
$EX^2+2EXY+EY^2-E^2X-E^2Y-2EXEY...EX^2 -E^2X+EY^2-E^2Y$
$EXY...-EXEY$
From **1.** we know that there is no relation between there expressions.

**3.** $Var(XY)...Var(X)Var(Y)$
I have no idea how to check it.
Can you help me ?  I also ask for checking my reasoing (and results :)) in **1.,2.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Recall the definition of covariance.
   $$\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y) = \mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(Y)$$

Covariance may be positive or negative (or zero), so...

2. Use the definition of variance.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf{Var}(X+Y) ~=~& \mathsf E(X^2+2XY+Y^2)-\mathsf E(X+Y)^2
\\ =~& \mathsf E(X^2)+2\mathsf E(XY)+\mathsf E(Y^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2-2\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(Y)-\mathsf E(Y)^2
\\ \ddots& \end{align}$$

And again, covariance may be positive or negative (or zero), so...

3. Well. 
   $$\begin{align}\mathsf{Var}(XY) ~=~& \mathsf E(X^2Y^2)-\mathsf E(XY)^2
   \\ \mathsf {Var}(X)\mathsf {Var}(Y) ~=~& (\mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2)(\mathsf E(Y^2)-\mathsf E(Y)^2)
   \\ =~& \mathsf E(X^2)\mathsf E(Y^2)-\mathsf E(X^2)\mathsf E(Y)^2-\mathsf E(X)^2\mathsf E(Y^2)+\mathsf E(X)^2\mathsf E(Y)^2
   \end{align}$$

There does not seem to be anything to indicate a general inequality between these two either.

Comment: 1., 2, 3. has no any relation.  Two questions: What about 3. in case of independent variables ?  What about my example for 1. ?